# Execute script as root with home folder decrypted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, encryption, luks

Is there a possibility to run a script as root on startup whilst also being able to access files in the encrypted home dir?

I know of `/etc/rc.local` which can execute scripts as root but since the user hasn't logged in, I can't access files in the home dir

I also know of the startup *.desktop files in `~/.config/autostart/` they can access the home dir since they are executed after login but they aren't run as root.

I want to automount my LUKS encrypted partition whilst using a key file that's in the encryted home directory. The commands `mount` and `cryptsetup` require root.

I prefer not to exclude these commands from requiring sudo rights, so this option is not available.

Comment: What encryption method is used for the home dir?

Comment: The home dir is encrypted with `eCryptfs`

Comment: If you don't need the contents of the LUKS partition immediately, you can run a cron job every minute that waits for your homedir to be decrypted and executes the mount command if the disk isn't there already.

Comment: That's a neat idea, but since I have my keepass safe on the LUKS partition which I need immediatly sadly this won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've almost got your answer already:

1. Have to wait until after the user logs in to decrypt their home
2. Then have to run commands as root, while still requiring `sudo`

- I think you'll just have to have a terminal or window popup after logging in asking for sudo privileges.

  Just create a .desktop file in `~/.config/autostart` that runs the commands/script prefaced with `sudo`, similar to

  ```
  Exec=sh -c "sudo cryptsetup... && sudo mount..."
  ```

  If plain `sudo` won't popup an "enter password" prompt, then `gksu` sounds like the tool you want to use instead of `sudo`.
- Or modify your sudo/sudoers to only run your specific script file without asking for a password, only for your user, something like this (but see `man sudoers` for pages & pages of info):

  ```
  myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/myuser/onlythis
  ```
- Or creating a PAM module/plugin to automatically 
  do things with your password while logging in is another, more complicated idea)